# Why I can't set up an SSH tunnel? Bad local forwarding specification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I sshed to my bastion host which has public IP. Now I try to set up an SSH tunnel by using the bastion host and executing the command

```
ssh -L 4000:10.0.0.182 ec2-user@54.236.29.63
```

I got

```
Bad local forwarding specification '4000:10.0.0.182'
```

What does that mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: - System Manager Agent must be installed and running (version 2.3.672.0 or more recent, see instructions for Linux or Windows). The agent is installed and started by default on Amazon Linux 1 & 2, Windows and Ubuntu AMIs provided by Amazon (see this page for the exact versions), no action is required when you are using these.
 - the EC2 instance must have an IAM role with permission to invoke Systems Manager API. For this example, I am using AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore. 
More information at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a wrong value to the `-L` option.

From the `ssh(1)` manual page:

```
 -L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
 -L [bind_address:]port:remote_socket
 -L local_socket:host:hostport
 -L local_socket:remote_socket
```

Try using `-L 4000:10.0.0.182:4000`, this way whenever a connection is made to the local port `4000` (on your local station), the connection will be forwarded to `10.0.0.182:4000`.